# How to pass elements of two arrays to a parallel command with :::

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run several python commands in parallel with the parallel command.

I tried playing around with the parallel command but it didn't perform as what I expected

Here's my shell script

```
arr_1=(a.log b.log c.log d.log)
arr_2=(a.json b.json c.json d.json)
parallel --halt 2 echo "{1} {2}" ::: "${arr_1[@]}" ::: ${arr_2{@}}
```

What I expected is:

```
a.log a.json
b.log b.json
c.log c.json
d.log d.json
```

But what I got was:

```
a.log a.json
b.log b.json
c.log c.json
d.log d.json
a.log a.json
b.log b.json
c.log c.json
d.log d.json
a.log a.json
b.log b.json
c.log c.json
d.log d.json
a.log a.json
b.log b.json
c.log c.json
d.log d.json
```

It looks like the shell script ran the command 16 times.

My guess is I didn't pass the two lists correctly, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: An alternative? `for ((i=0; i<${#arr_1[@]}; i++)); do echo "${arr_1[$i]} ${arr_2[$i]}" & done`

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks that will do. Just one more question regrading the usage of `&`. Let's say I have to finish for-loop A first then run for-loop B. In this case, do I need to add `wait` at the end of for-loop A so that it can wait for all the parallel jobs done?

Comment: @patl yes, just add a `wait` between the loops if for-loop B needs the commands to complete before running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `:::+`:

```
parallel --halt 2 echo "{1} {2}" ::: "${arr_1[@]}" :::+ ${arr_2[@]}
```

Available since 20160422.